# Blazor Server trying SignalR Error 401 (unauthorized) using Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, blazor, signalr, blazor-server-side, signalr.client

Hey im having a hard time trying to realtime refreshing (without refreshing the page) my Blazor App.

*Initial* *Problem*: I have an admin page where admins can change the role of users. The roles are then stored in a database. The user sees the changes only when he reloads the page. Now I was looking for a solution and just found SignalR and tried to integrate it into my project.

Before we get to the problem with SignalR I want to show you how I integrated the Authorization in my Blazor Server Applikation.

I have a Class named **UserRoleManager.cs** which gets the current AuthenticaitonSate and some data from the currentUser such as RoleId. After that i fill in the ClaimTypes.GroupSid with the roleIds which the User has. To use the AuthenticationStateProvider on every Site I call this Class and Method in my **App.razor**.

**App.razor**

```
@code {
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await UserRoleManager.UpdateUserRole();
    }
}
```

**UserRoleManager.cs**

```
public async Task UpdateUserRole()
        {
            var authState = await _authenticationStateProvider.GetAuthenticationStateAsync();
            var user = authState.User;

            var userRolesList = _userRoleService.GetUserRolesListe();

            var currentUser = userRolesList.Where(ur => ur.WindowsUser == user.Identity?.Name)
                                    .ToList();
            if (currentUser != null)
            {
                foreach (var roleId in currentUser)
                {
                    var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)user.Identity!;
                    claimsIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GroupSid, roleId.RoleId.ToString()));
                }
            }
        }
```

I tried following the steps from the [Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/tutorials/signalr-blazor?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code).

**UserRoleHub.cs**:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;

namespace MultipleProjectsSyncfusion.Hubs
{
    public class UserRoleHub : Hub
    {
        public async Task UpdateUserRoles(string userId)
        {
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("UpdateRoles", userId);
        }
    }
}
```

Change in my UserRoleManager.cs:

```
public async Task UpdateUserRole()
{
 //.. irrelevant Code 
            var username = currentUser.FirstOrDefault(ur => ur.WindowsUser == user.Identity?.Name);

            var hubContext = _hubContext.Clients.All;
            await hubContext.SendAsync("UpdateUserRoles", username?.WindowsUser);
}
```

**Admin.razor**

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // irrelevant Code 

        hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
     .WithUrl(NavigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri("/userhub"))
     .Build();

        hubConnection.On<string>("ReceiveRoleChangeNotification", async (user) =>
        {

            SelectedUser = user;
            StateHasChanged(); // Aktualisiere die Benutzeroberfläche

        });


        await hubConnection.StartAsync();
    }
```

**Error**: This is the Error which I get after running my Blazor Server Projekt: *HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).*

Comment: This is a [known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25000#issue-681048648) reported over 3 years ago. I don't think MS will be fixing this one so you will likely have to take a different approach.

Comment: yeah there is a [workaround](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25000#issuecomment-795685660) but unfortunatly it only works locally